# Template Rendered callback in Meteor 0.8.0 blaze

Tags: javascript, meteor

With this update and the introduction to the new template engine Blaze, I'm having a few issues, more specifically with the Template Rendered callback.

The one along the lines of `template.my_template.rendered` no longer seems to work for me. Giving me undefined when I try to log (`this._id`) and none of the content inside of it actually works.

I read in the introduction to blaze that `Meteor.render` has been removed. Do the two of these have anything in common? What's the updated syntax to do this if it has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `this._id` in your Template rendered callback, try using `this.data._id` instead, now. I'm a bit unsure why `this._id` worked for you in the rendered callback before.

If it was your helper and not your rendered callback it would remain as `this._id`, however some rules have changed depending on whether your template is within another template.

There is a [migration guide](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze) that can help you structure your templates for blaze. You could also post here but given the details you have provided there isn't enough information to determine what the real issue is.

`Meteor.render` is deprecated. There is a new UI.render namespace (http://docs.meteor.com/#ui) that can do something similar. It depends what you want to do, but UI.insertWithData may do something similar.

See the migration docs on Meteor.render: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#meteorrender-has-been-removed

Comment: After reading the rendered callback is different from what Meteor.render is. The issue is that the rendered callback is only called once now.

Comment: @user1952811 Yes the rendered callback only fires once now. This is because Blaze works by DOM patching. It shouldn't have to fire more than once. When the DOM changes it shouldn't break anything like with Spark when the rendered callback was needed to re-initialize any Jquery components

Comment: How should I go about updating in a nice and automatic manner now? I see other questions with no answers

Comment: @user1952811 I can help you out here. Please update the question with your exact problem so that I can reproduce it. If it is something about doing something when something changes you could use Deps.autorun instead.